# Is it possible to post json to mvc controller without jQuery?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I would like to post several input values to controller as a json string with only one method argument for example:

```
<input name="x" value="">
<input name="y" value="">

public void GetAsJson(string json)
{

}
```

And doing so without jQuery and with default model binding?

Comment: jQuery is just a wrapper around vanilla JavaScript. Everything it does is possible without it.

Comment: Ok thank you, for clarification I mean without any kind of javascript and only with asp.net and html post.

Comment: server side you could post it with HttpClient.

Comment: The "js" in json does stand for javascript. :)  If you don' want any javascript at all, you can simply post the form to a controller, but then it's not in json, If the form adheres to your viewmodel, then it should model bind automatically.

Comment: Ok another clarification, JavaScript is ok, but under the hood of asp.net :)

Comment: I currently have the same problem.
My javascript is reasonable, but sending an object to the prescribed ajax call and then parsing and have an action register it as a parameter is eluding me.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to perform what you are saying without any kind of Javascript at all. With JSON, the JS stands for Javascript and Javascript is needed to perform an Ajax call anyways.

Here is how I would do it.

Remember that on the C# side of things that you aren't really accepting a JSON object, you are actually just accepting a list.

Here is the post that you are wanting. It is almost a string like you suggested however, the difference is because in your AJAX call, you need to specify the JSON.stringify and the dataType: json.

```
public ActionResult FruitPost(List<String> Fruit)
    {
        return null;
    }
```

Here is the view:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function submitForm() {
        var fruit = ["apple", "orange", "bananna"];

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "@Url.Action("FruitPost")",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify(fruit),
            success: function (data) { alert(data); },
            failure: function (errMsg) {
                alert(errMsg);
            }
        });
    }
</script>

<input type="button" value="Click" onclick="submitForm()"/>
```

If you are DEAD SET on doing an ajax call without JQuery... I would suggest reading this: https://www.sitepoint.com/guide-vanilla-ajax-without-jquery/
After doing so, you might change your mind.